# transitioning to a new value in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-tsx

So I am kind of new to this three js library and I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this issue;

the plan is to render a rotating shape whose size changes periodically (say every 2 seconds),
and the size value is generated and passed from a backend using websocket.

now the plan is whenever the new value comes in from the backend the shape transitions smoothly to the new value. So far, I have achieved a jumpy shape that doesn't transition smoothly. if there is something I'm missing please let me know thanks!

**Note**:  this is a React-typescript application

**current code snippet**:

[image: current code snippet]

Comment: The "smooth transition" you're referring to is called "tweening" where a set of smaller intermediate values are calculated, and the transition happens over a span of time over that set. There is no official tweening library for three.js, but searching for the terms will give you the popular ones.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)